# Sharepoint CSWP - Link URL - Open in new window

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, content-search-web-part

I have a CSWP which I have configured - added a new URL Column and redirected links to the new location. The issue is now getting the links to open in a new window. The new custom column is a text field.

Does anyone have a work around for this one?

Comment: you want the link to be opened in same tab, in which search results are appearing?

Comment: No - in a new window.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, I would create a new CSWP display template.  That way you can add in the code (shown highlighted in yellow) that will make the link open in a new window.

[image]

I usually copy the Item_TwoLines.html display template and modify for my needs.  You can find it in the site collection master page gallery > Display Templates > Content Search Web Parts.

If you've never created a display template before, here is one intro but there are plenty of others. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945138.aspx

Comment: This is just what I am looking for - I Will give it a go and let you know if I am successful.

Comment: Hi Robin - just realised the code has been cut off at the ends - would you mind reposting it??

Comment: Here is the code you need to replace.  In mine this is line 59.

<a class="cbs-ItemLink" title="_#= $htmlEncode(line1.defaultValueRenderer(line1)) =#_" id="_#= pictureLinkId =#_" target="new">

Comment: I am using the Large Picture Display Template - I have added the change to the template - still no success.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Robin - thanks so much - I realised I had not changed the webpart to match the new template. working well now.